# Prestashop category links showing database access denied error

Tags: prestashop-1.6

check my website:-

http://mokingo.com/en

If you will click on some product category link most of them will display some database error, but i am sure that this error was not coming previously it is so wierd can anyone help with it.

Check this url for the error

http://mokingo.com/en/14-kids-baby

Comment: Please do not link to your site, paste the error and describe the context instead.

Comment: @JitendraRai did you update you prestashop version or any of the modules recently? Also do you have ssl on?

Comment: [PrestaShopDatabaseException]

Access denied for user 'cl56-zcube0786'@'%' to database 'cl56-zcube0786'


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ps_cat_restriction ENGINE=MEMORY
             SELECT DISTINCT cp.id_product, p.id_manufacturer, product_shop.condition, p.weight FROM ps_category_product cp
             INNER JOIN ps_category c ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category AND
             c.nleft >= 226
             AND

Comment: Please check i have mentioned the error in the comment

Comment: Can you check your config folder and see this file settings.inc.php ? In that check the db username and password and db name. Are they correct??

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that your mysql has insufficient privileges to create temporary tables and, possibly, some other privileges.

You can check this from phpmyadmin by running the following query:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

If you have all necessary permissions the output should be like:

> Grants for yourusername_pshop@% GRANT USAGE ON . TO
>   'yourusername_pshop'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'YOURPASSWORDHASH'
>   GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER,
>   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW,
>   CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON yourusername_pshop.* TO
>   'yourusername_pshop'@'%'

For more details see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36859632/6255277