# Prestashop 1.6 Issue with horizontal menu and category menu

Tags: exception

I encounter this error after when i tried to change my default currency to dollarwebsite is aso-iyi.com
Whenever I click on one of the horizontal menu icon (e.g african prints) it will display the following line of code below
themes am using is default bootstrap

```
[PrestaShopDatabaseException]

Access denied for user 'cl50-x-prest-xxx'@'%' to database 'cl50-x-prest-xxx'

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ps_cat_restriction ENGINE=MEMORY

SELECT DISTINCT cp.id_product, p.id_manufacturer, product_shop.condition, p.weight FROM ps_category_product cp
                                                    INNER JOIN ps_category c ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category AND
                                                    c.nleft >= 10
                                                    AND c.nright <= 11
                                                    AND c.active = 1)
                                                    INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON (product_shop.id_product = cp.id_product
                                                    AND product_shop.id_shop = 1)
                                                    INNER JOIN ps_product p ON (p.id_product=cp.id_product)
                                                    WHERE product_shop.`active` = 1 AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")

throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
635.            throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
```

check my website for more proper explanation
www-aso-iyi.com click on african prints at the horizontal menu

Will appreciate so much

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem and found out that it's reason is unsufficient privileges for your mysql user.
Originally, when I created my database in the hosting panel I was offered to create a user for the database with FULL privileges. Of course I used this option. But after spending few hours with this problem - i tried to move my existing prestashop database and prestashop directories and files to localhost and checked if the categories list works. It was a surprise - but this error disappeared. Then I exported the dump of local database back to my hosting, and got the same error again.

After that i have explored menu in the hosting panel to add/edit mysql users and found that my user, which should have all privileges with DB does not have all privileges.

The following privileges were missing:

- create temporary tables [!!! if you look at your error you can see that the SQL query tries to create temporary table in memory (ENGINE=MEMORY), but indeed we do not have this permission and get access denied error]
- create routine
- alter routine
- create view 
  etc.

After adding all those permissions the subject error disappeared and I can view/browse the products in my categories.

If you have access to phpmyadmin you can check your permissions by running the following SQL query:

`SHOW GRANTS;`

If you have all necessary permissions the output should be like:

```
Grants for yourusername_pshop@%
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'yourusername_pshop'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'YOURPASSWORDHASH'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `yourusername_pshop`.* TO 'yourusername_pshop'@'%'
```

Hope it will be helpful

P.S. if you can not find out how to check and change you mysql user permissions - it would be better to contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

How i solve the horizontal menu not displaying and whenever I click on it THAT WILL DISPLAY DATABASE EXCEPTION ERRROR...ACCESS DENIED.
i first confirm my user database name, database name and password at /public_html/config/settings.inc.php with the one i have at my control panel hosting account. When it is the same
and the problem still persist, i disable my horizontal menu module at module section then i go through my /public_html/config/defines.inc.php line 29 and line 36 i set them to false then i go to the back office .. CLICK ON preference then click on seo & url to check if there is any conflicting url then i saw A third party payment module page and order module having the same url of "order-confirmation" then i changed the third part payment url since is a third party module and i install it new then i enable my horizontal menu module back then everything started working perfectly